# macOS Sierra and (wired) keyboard broken

Tags: keyboard, macos

I've updated my macbook pro to macOS Sierra and now my (apple) wired keyboard is completely broken.

I'm using a AZERTY wired keyboard (like the one on my macbook) but even if on my macbook every keys seems correct, on the wired keyboard two keys are reversed : @ and <
[image]

---

Also on both keyboards when I shift + click it doesn't select anymore on anything (text, file, spreadsheet, etc.)
Same for Ctrl + click

It was working before the update.

---

Also some **really weird behaviour**, for example on Steam. When I chat with someone from my desktop, there is no problem. But when I chat with him in-game I got these japanese or chinese characters whatever key I press :

[image]

Also Shift+tab don't work to access at Steam while in-game.

---

And here are just a few.... I keep discovering new ones every day.

*Everything was working perfectly before the update.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved all the issues. On the previous version (OS X) I was using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). On macOS Sierra since it was not working I've installed [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).

I've deleted all of these, make sure to delete all the file. Rebooted. And now **all is working properly**.